# SitecoreQuery issue in glass mapper

Tags: glass-mapper

I use glass mapper 5.3 and I use SitecoreQuery in this field:

```
[SitecoreQuery("/sitecore/content/Newsroom/Data/Enumerations/Companies/*")]
public virtual IEnumerable<EnumerationValueItem> Companies { get; set; }
```

Here is the definition for EnumerationValueItem

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=IEnumerationValueItemConstants.TemplateIdString)] //, Cachable = true
public partial class EnumerationValueItem  : GlassBase, IEnumerationValueItem 
{
    [SitecoreField(IEnumerationValueItemConstants.ValueFieldName)]
    public virtual string Value  {get; set;}                
}
```

If I use this code, then company.Value returns "$name" (this is standard value)

```
foreach(EnumerationValueItem company in Model.Companies)
{
    Response.Write(company.Value);
}
```

If I use this code, then x.Value return correct value

```
var  x = WebContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<EnumerationValueItem>("/sitecore/content/Newsroom/Data/Enumerations/Companies/google");
Response.Write(x.Value);
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get the model which contains `Companies` property? I assume it could be something related to language verison of the item and `VersionCountDisabler`.

Comment: the module that inherits the model class which contains Companies property